# Retrieving User from Salesforce failing with 411 error

Tags: api, sobject

I'm attempting to retrieve a custom object record by one of it's unique fields using the built in api. For this specific call, my request is is:

```
path: `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/YTPStudent__c/drupalId__c/39111`
method: GET
headers:
  Authorization: 8248...3483
  Content-Type: application/json
```

When I do this on Postman, it works fine. I get the proper response. However, when I make the **exact** same call via Drupal., it's failing with this html:

[image: error]

And the response body is this:

```
Code: 411
Error: length required
```

Is the 411 a false error? It doesn't make much sense why it works for one platform but not another....

Comment: ...because the calls are different, it's likely that Drupal version of this is making a POST request which requires content length. This site works best when you can show us the code you've written so far and point to a specific part of it that you're struggling with. If you do have code you can share with us, you should edit your question to include it (and use the {} button to format it). Please see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more info

Comment: Don't patronize me. Considering this was a question that had nothing to do with salesforce code but rather it's built-in functionality, there is no need to add any code.

Comment: Also, you didn't read my question when I pointed out that BOTH postman and Drupal were making GET requests. Please read throughly before answering.

Comment: Turns out, this occurred because Salesforce freaks out and gives a falsy error when Content-Length is provided in a GET request. Drupal was automatically adding Content-Length to a request if data was sent (not sure how data got sent in the request). So, on Salesforce's API, if you provide `Content-Length` in the headers on a GET request, it will throw a `411: Content-Length Required` error. Nicely done Salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You for answered your own question. It works perfectly!

> Turns out, this occurred because Salesforce freaks out and gives a falsy error when Content-Length is provided in a GET request. Drupal was automatically adding Content-Length to a request if data was sent (not sure how data got sent in the request). So, on Salesforce's API, if you provide Content-Length in the headers on a GET request, it will throw a 411: Content-Length Required error. Nicely done Salesforce –
> BlondeSwan
> Jan 17 '20 at 1:00